# How to create file and folder then save that file into a folder?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to create a folder and then save my file into that folder. I wrote code that automatically creates a file and I want to save the file into a folder. I have tried many codes but none ever work. Below is my last code that I have tried but it still does not work:

```
void rooms() {
    Name rooms;
    Name rooms2;
    Name rooms3;
    Name staff;
    int b;
    char choicedo;
    string filename;
    string input;

    do
    {
        ofstream bilik2;
        bilik2.open("rooms2.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        if(!bilik2)
        {
            cout<<"File Not Found!";
            exit(1);
        }
        if(bilik2 == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error! Rooms is empty!";
            break;
        }

        ofstream bilik3;
        bilik3.open("rooms3.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        if(!bilik3)
        {
            cout<<"File Not Found!";
            exit(1);
        }
        if(bilik3 == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error! Rooms is empty!";
            break;
        }

        cout<<"1. Single Rooms "<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Family Rooms "<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Royal Rooms "<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"\nRooms type: ";
        cin >> b;
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Please fill in requirement information "<<endl;
        switch(b)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                cout<<"Room No: ";
                cin>>filename;
                input = filename;
                cin.ignore();
                //ofstream input("C:\\Users\\Dr. Akilah\\Desktop\\BLUE\\single room");
                mkdir("singleroom");
                ofstream outfile("singleroom");

                //system("mkdir singleroom");
                outfile.write(input.c_str(), input.size());
                input += ".txt";
                outfile.close();

                ifstream ifile(input.c_str());
                if(ifile)
                {
                    cout<<"Room is already exist."<<endl;
                    exit(1);
                }

                ofstream out(input.c_str());
                //out.open("C:/Users/Dr. Akilah/Desktop/BLUE/single room/ ", ios::out | ios::app);

                ofstream bilik;
                bilik.open(input.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Air Conditioner: ";
                cin.getline(rooms.airc, 20);
                cout<<"Date: ";
                cin.getline(rooms.date, 20);
                cout<<"Insert by: ";
                cin.getline(staff.first, 20);

                bilik<<"List of Single Rooms"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                bilik<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                bilik<<endl;
                bilik<<"               Room No: "<<filename<<endl;
                bilik<<endl;
                bilik<<"Air Conditioner: "<<rooms.airc<<endl;
                bilik<<endl;
                bilik<<"Regsitration Date: "<<rooms.date<<endl;
                bilik<<endl;
                bilik<<"Created by: "<<staff.first<<endl;
                bilik<<endl;
                bilik<<endl;
                bilik<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                bilik.close();
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Room no: ";
                cin>>rooms2.room;
                cin.ignore();
                cout<<"Air Conditioner: ";
                cin.getline(rooms2.airc, 20);
                cout<<"Date: ";
                cin.getline(rooms2.date, 20);
                cout<<"Insert by: ";
                cin.getline(staff.first, 20);
                break;
            }

            case 3:
            {
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Room no: ";
                cin>>rooms3.room;
                cin.ignore();
                cout<<"Air Conditioner: ";
                cin.getline(rooms3.airc, 20);
                cout<<"Date: ";
                cin.getline(rooms3.date, 20);
                cout<<"Insert by: ";
                cin.getline(staff.first, 20);
                break;
            }

            default:
                cout<<"Invalid choice "<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                Sleep(1000);
                //return 0;
        }

        cout<<"Enter Y To input an other data or Enter N to Exit: ";
        cin>>choicedo;
        cout<<"_____________________________________"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    while (choicedo=='y' || choicedo=='Y');
}
```

When I compile this code:

[image]

This error appears:

[image]

So, how can I fix this error? And how can I save my file into a folder?

Comment: Click that link to see my photos. Sorry for any inconvenience, this is my first time using this website. Thanks.

Comment: Don't post links to images of text. Don't even post images of text. Copy-paste the actual text into the body of the question instead. Please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).You should probably learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well.

Comment: By the way, what *is* your question? Is it about the build error? Or is it how to create a folder and then create a file inside that folder? One question per question please!

Comment: The main question is I want to create a folder then save my files into that folder.

Comment: You already know how to do that (`mkdir()` and `std::ofstream`), so what is the REAL problem you are having with them?  Probably due to the fact that you are using **relative paths**.  Always use **absolute paths** instead.

Comment: I know haw to create folder. but I don'y know how to save my file into that folder. I want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::ostream::put`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put) takes a *single* character, not a C-string; for that, you should instead use [`std::ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write):

```
outfile.write(input.c_str(), input.size());
```

Comment: I tried this code, but my file still saves in the main folder, not in the folder that I want to save it, in this case, the folder that I name it singleroom.

Comment: Because you haven't posted actual code, I can't help with that problem; with the little you've shown, the compile error is all I can help with. Please read the links posted by @Someprogrammerdude and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you show me the simplest way to save a file into a folder. Thanks.

Comment: That's too broad of a request; but _post your code_ and I might be able to help correct whatever problem it has. That's sort of how this site works... ;-]

Comment: I posted my part of code. Please review it. The problem is in Case 1.

Comment: You're creating a folder named `singleroom` then telling the filestream to write to a file named `singleroom`. Add a filename to the path you're using for `outfile` or take out the `mkdir` call so that `singleroom` can be created as a file.

Comment: But my file is automatically creates using this code: input += ".txt";

Comment: That has nothing to do with the filename you're passing to `outfile`'s constructor, which is hardcoded as `"singleroom"`.